# Is there a way to use a macro to insert a comment in whichever cell I've selected and automatically deletes the username?

Tags: vba, excel

The point of this is that I have a column of cells in which I'd like to put a comment in each cell (which I move up and down with sort). However I'm a bit too lazy to go through hundreds of cells and each time having to delete the username when I insert a blank comment for future use. So I thought it'd be easier, if I could select a cell and just press a shortcut key instead.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 1):

```
Activecell.AddComment ("test") or  Activecell.AddComment ("")
```

Comment: You don't need the parenthesis, since you are not expecting a return value. Should be just `Activecell.Addcomment "test"` Still, yours works, but a bit misleading.

Answer (score 1):

Excel VBA has decent online help

```
With Worksheets(1).Range("e6").AddComment
    .Visible = False
    .Text ""
End With
```

Answer (score 1):

Assign a shortcut key to this macro:

```
Sub BlankComments()
    Dim r As Range

    For Each r In Selection
        r.ClearComments
        r.AddComment Text:=""
    Next r
End Sub
```

Select some cells and run the macro.